# C# Collect IOps PErformance Data RealTime?

Tags: c#, performancecounter, provisioned-iops

I am trying to build a small Software App which can collect Performance Data from a Windows Machine.

Here is a part of the code i use and PrintScreen which gives me not a right number.
Please Tell me what is wrong in my Code and why is the scale not right in the code.(The default scale is 1)

PrintScreen:
http://postimage.org/image/6za0g7e4t/

```
ManagementScope oMs = new System.Management.ManagementScope("root\\cimv2");
                //Inventory
                ObjectQuery InventQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Inventsearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oMs, InventQuery);
                ManagementObjectCollection InventCollection = Inventsearcher.Get();

                foreach (ManagementObject mgt in InventCollection)
                {
                    outBox.AppendText(mgt["csname"].ToString() + "\n");
                }

                //Performance
                //ObjectQuery PerfQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk");
                ObjectQuery PerfQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Perfsearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oMs, PerfQuery);
                ManagementObjectCollection PerfCollection = Perfsearcher.Get();

                foreach (ManagementObject mgt in PerfCollection)
                {
                    mgt.SetPropertyQualifierValue("DiskWritesPerSec", "DefaultScale", ScaleBox.Text);
                    mgt.SetPropertyQualifierValue("DiskReadsPerSec", "DefaultScale", ScaleBox.Text);
                    outBox.AppendText("Write IOps: " + mgt["Name"].ToString() + " ");
                    outBox.AppendText("Write IOps: " + mgt["DiskWritesPerSec"].ToString() + " ");
                    outBox.AppendText("Read  IOps: " + mgt["DiskReadsPerSec"].ToString() + "\n");
                }
```

Comment: We can't help you unless you give us more information on the error that is occurring. What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: I don't get an error,i added a Printscreen that you can see that the numbers in Performance Monitor are diffrent than the Number i see in the collection in my software.